Le type de la subordonnée conjonctive, relative ou circonstancielle
De quel type est la subordonnée dans la phrase suivante :

Donnez-lui enfin la réponse qu'il attend.


Welcome to French.SE! I've been practising French for 60yrs and haven't a clue as to what the type of a subordinate is good for. What problem(s) do you intend to solve with this knowledge, and what is unsatisfactory in the solutions you found so far?

Subordonnée relative, le pronom relative qu' se rapportant à la réponse.

Comme Frank a dit en commentaire, c'est un subordonné relative complément de l'antécédent réponse, aussi essayez de remplacer qu' par dont (un autre pronom relatif), elle gardera le même sens.

La réponse dont il attend ?

Peu clair.  Elle ?  La traduction automatique ?  En tout cas que et dont ne sont pas interchangeables.
